# Word for people who are pretending to be making effort

Tags: phrase-request

What are the right words or phrases that describe a person who is pretending to be working hard or contributing to a team effort, actually doing nothing but waiting to get a (undeserved) share of reward?

I tried to look it up in a dictionary from my mother tongue to English, and I did not find any words or phrases, only full sentences.

Comment: [bloodsucker, freeloader, free rider, hanger-on, moocher, parasite, sponge, sponger](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/freeloader)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One term that could be used is ***coaster***.

It was hard to find a dictionary that listed this meaning of the word, but I managed to find one on the [Wordnik page](http://www.wordnik.com/words/coaster).  One of Wordnik's cross-listed definition reads:

> **coaster** (*n*.) A loafer.

In my experience, the word is often used when a member of a team is relying too much on others, and not contributing enough. This could be a sports team, or a team working on a project in school or the workplace. The verb form was used in a headline earlier this year, when a reporter wondered:

> [**Dwyane Wade: Is Miami Heat Star on the Decline or Just *Coasting*?**](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1517993-dwyane-wade-is-miami-heat-star-on-the-decline-or-just-coasting)

As a synonym, you could probably use ***slacker***. NOAD defines the word as:

> **slacker** (*n*.) A person who avoids work or effort.

If the context makes it clear that the slacker is a member of a team, I think the word can carry the meaning you want.

Comment: Does 'loafer' mean the same?

Comment: A loafer is usually regarded as a lazy person. The word might work, depending on how it was used. If I said, "Bill and Ted worked their butts off, but Randy was a real loafer," then, yes, that would work. I think _coaster_ comes a little closer to "pretending" to make an effort, though, because those people are "coasting along" from the work of others. Think of a tandem bike where one person isn't pedaling, but merely coasting.

Comment: To me, coasting is putting in the minimum effort to not get fired, not *pretending* to do work as the OP asked.

Comment: @StephenS - The way I read the question, the OP asked about someone who is pretending to work _hard_, not someone who is pretending to work. But, either way, these are subtle differences that wouldn't really change my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a word or simple phrase that incorporates "pretending to be working hard or contributing", but someone who isn't contributing while expecting to share in rewards could be called a "free rider" or, more pejoratively, a "[straphanger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straphanger#Pejorative_use)".

Comment: In the UK, a *straphanger* would normally be understood to mean a *commuter* (particularly one using the London Underground to get to work).

Answer (score 2):

The word that I would use is "shirker." In your (Chinese) language, this word would correspond to the ideogram of a woman talking, while carrying (or pretending to) a stack of grain.

Answer (score 2):

[Fudgel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fudgel) is an old (18th century?) English word that means “to pretend to be busy while actually doing nothing.”

A [Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/mark-forsyth/weird-phrases_b_4018105.html) article reads:

> To *fudgel* is an eighteenth-century term meaning “Pretending to work when you’re not actually doing anything at all.” Modern offices are full of it, largely because when somebody is staring intently at a computer screen and typing it’s hard to tell whether they’re busily putting together this year’s accounts or busily updating their Facebook status or buying something on eBay. “Stop fudgelling” should be the catchphrase of every efficient office manager.

Comment: I wouldn't expect most people to know what this means, but maybe one day it will be a "comeback word", along with the likes of [deliciate](https://matadornetwork.com/abroad/20-obsolete-english-words-that-should-make-a-comeback/) and [overmorrow](http://www.businessinsider.com/olde-english-words-we-need-to-start-using-again-2016-4).

Answer (score 1):

[Goldbricker](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/goldbricking.asp) has the meaning you want

> person who gets paid a wage, or salary, for work that is not done, despite the appearance of working.

but is unusual.  And possibly old-fashioned -- I've found it in writing from the WWII era.

Answer (score 0):

I like the phrase *coat-hanger* myself, someone who hovers around actually doing nothing is only really fit to hold your coat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that suitable words for this sense are a freeloader and a hanger-on.

Answer (score 0):

Boondoggle:

verb (used without object), boon·dog·gled, boon·dog·gling.
to do work of little or no practical value merely to keep or look busy.

Comment: A boondoggle can refer to the project itself, but not to the people working on it.